# Java Script: How to Replace the multiple strings based on conditions

Tags: javascript, string

Below string is in the format of name and value (' name' - 'value';).
How to remove the occurrence of value `'0 bytes'` along with its name and 
remove the name `'/platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1'` along with its value.

> /devices - 0 bytes; /system/object - 0 bytes; /etc/dfs/sharetab - 0
>   bytes; /dev/fd - 0 bytes; /var/run - 13.77 GiB;
>   /platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1 - 27.24 GiB; / - 27.24 GiB;
>   /var - 26.84 GiB; /proc - 0 bytes; /system/contract - 0 bytes; /rpool
>   - 18.04 GiB; /mnt - 157.67 TiB; /vol - 0 bytes; /was8 - 48.26 GiB; /platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1 - 27.24 GiB; /etc/svc/volatile -
>   13.77 GiB; /etc/mnttab - 0 bytes; /tmp - 13.82 GiB;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string on a selicolon and filter the array based on your criteria, then join the array to add back the semicolons and convert back to one string:

```
var str = '/devices - 0 bytes; /system/object - 0 bytes; /etc/dfs/sharetab - 0 bytes; /dev/fd - 0 bytes; /var/run - 13.77 GiB; /platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1 - 27.24 GiB; / - 27.24 GiB; /var - 26.84 GiB; /proc - 0 bytes; /system/contract - 0 bytes; /rpool - 18.04 GiB; /mnt - 157.67 TiB; /vol - 0 bytes; /was8 - 48.26 GiB; /platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1 - 27.24 GiB; /etc/svc/volatile - 13.77 GiB; /etc/mnttab - 0 bytes; /tmp - 13.82 GiB;'

var splitStr = str.split(';');
var newStr = splitStr.filter(function(item){
         var itemSplit = item.split('-');

         return !(itemSplit != '' && (itemSplit[0].trim() ===  '/platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1'  || itemSplit[1].trim() ==='0 bytes'));
}).join(';');

//newStr is will contain the filtered string
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions here to transform the string.

**See:**

1. The first regex (`/\/platform\/sun4v\/lib\/sparcv9\/libc_psr\.so\.1 [^\;]+\;\s/`) selects the long, unique substring;
2. The second regex (`/\/[^\-]+- 0 bytes\;\s/g`) selects all instances of `- 0 bytes` (and each instance's preceding label)

```js
var paragraphAfter = document.getElementsByClassName('after')[0];
var textBefore = document.getElementsByClassName('before')[0].textContent;
var textAfter = textBefore.replace(/\/platform\/sun4v\/lib\/sparcv9\/libc_psr\.so\.1 [^\;]+\;\s/,'');
var textAfter = textAfter.replace(/\/[^\-]+- 0 bytes\;\s/g,'');
paragraphAfter.textContent = textAfter;
```

```html
<h2>Before:</h2>
<p class="before">/devices - 0 bytes; /system/object - 0 bytes; /etc/dfs/sharetab - 0 bytes; /dev/fd - 0 bytes; /var/run - 13.77 GiB; /platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1 - 27.24 GiB; /var - 26.84 GiB; /proc - 0 bytes; /system/contract - 0 bytes; /rpool - 18.04 GiB; /mnt - 157.67 TiB; /vol - 0 bytes; /was8 - 48.26 GiB; /platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1 - 27.24 GiB; /etc/svc/volatile - 13.77 GiB; /etc/mnttab - 0 bytes; /tmp - 13.82 GiB;</p>

<h2>After:</h2>
<p class="after"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
str.split(';').filter(item =>  !item.includes('0 bytes') && !item.includes('/platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1')).join(';')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you still want your output in the same format. This should work for you:

```
function formatInfo(data) {
    return data.split(";").filter(function(item,i) {
        if( item.indexOf('0 bytes') >= 0 || item.indexOf('/platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1') >= 0 ) {
            return null;
        }
        return item.trim();
    }).join(";").trim();
}
```

//Usage:

```
formatInfo('/devices - 0 bytes; /system/object - 0 bytes; /etc/dfs/sharetab - 0 bytes; /dev/fd - 0 bytes; /var/run - 13.77 GiB; /platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1 - 27.24 GiB; / - 27.24 GiB; /var - 26.84 GiB; /proc - 0 bytes; /system/contract - 0 bytes; /rpool - 18.04 GiB; /mnt - 157.67 TiB; /vol - 0 bytes; /was8 - 48.26 GiB; /platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1 - 27.24 GiB; /etc/svc/volatile - 13.77 GiB; /etc/mnttab - 0 bytes; /tmp - 13.82 GiB;');
```

//should return:

```
"/var/run - 13.77 GiB; / - 27.24 GiB; /var - 26.84 GiB; /rpool - 18.04 GiB; /mnt - 157.67 TiB; /was8 - 48.26 GiB; /platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1 - 27.24 GiB; /etc/svc/volatile - 13.77 GiB; /tmp - 13.82 GiB"
```

Cheers..!!